# SUM the results of GROUP BY whilst using the IN operator with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My query:

```
SELECT "Tracks"."PageId", date_trunc('month', "Tracks"."createdAt") AS month
FROM "Tracks"
WHERE "Tracks"."PageId" IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY month, "Tracks"."PageId"`)
```

However, this yields:

```
  [ { PageId: 30, month: Thu Sep 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) },
  { PageId: 29, month: Thu Sep 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) },
  { PageId: 31, month: Thu Sep 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) },
  { PageId: 29, month: Sat Oct 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) } ]
```

What's the best approach to also get the SUM of each `PageId`, ie. there were 3 of PageId 29 in October 2016, and 2 in September...

Comment: if you add `count(*)` as the last field, would that give you what you seek?

Comment: @Hambone Yes! Thanks!